# get raw sql query in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In User model I define relation :

```
\App\User::where('id' ,1)->toSql();
```

it return `select * from users where id = ?` how can I get full query including params?

Also I define relation with post model:

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Posts::class);
}
```

How to view full relational query with params?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about it: the Laravel way, and the MySQL way.

The Laravel way is to use the DB::getQueryLog();

```
\App\User::where('id' ,1)->get();
$queries = \DB::getQueryLog();
Log::info(end($queries)); // OR
dd(end($queries));
```

The MySQL way involves the general log.

```
mysql> show variables like 'general_log%';
+------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                        |
+------------------+------------------------------+
| general_log      | OFF                          |
| general_log_file | /var/lib/mysql/homestead.log |
+------------------+------------------------------+
```

Check your variables for the location of the log. Before the query, run `SET GLOBAL general_log = 1`, and make sure to set it back to 0 after the query is done. Then open up that log file, and you'll see both the Prepare and Execute lines.